# Using SwiftUI, how do I animate pie progress bar

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I've created the code for displaying the pie progress bar. I need to add an animation to this progress bar. I tried linear animation but it didn't help. I'm stuck and don't know how to get it to animate. Can someone help? Here's the code.

```
import SwiftUI

struct PieProgress: View {
    @State var progress: Float

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack(spacing:20) {
                HStack{
                    Text("0%")
                    Slider(value: self.$progress)
                    Text("100%")
                }.padding()
                Circle()
                    .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1)
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.width, alignment: .center)
                    .padding()
                    .overlay(
                        PieShape(progress: Double(self.progress))
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 10, height: geometry.size.width - 10 , alignment: .center)
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    )
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PieShape: Shape {
    var progress: Double = 0.0
    private let startAngle: Double = (Double.pi) * 1.5
    private var endAngle: Double {
        get {
            return self.startAngle + Double.pi * 2 * self.progress
        }
    }

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        let arcCenter =  CGPoint(x: rect.size.width / 2, y: rect.size.width / 2)
        let radius = rect.size.width / 2
        path.move(to: arcCenter)
        path.addArc(center: arcCenter, radius: radius, startAngle: Angle(radians: startAngle), endAngle: Angle(radians: endAngle), clockwise: false)
        path.closeSubpath()
        return path
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

With updated deprecated methods and now w/o hard-codes

[image: demo]

```
Circle()
    .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1)
    .overlay(
        PieShape(progress: Double(self.progress))
            .padding(4)
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
    )
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    .animation(Animation.linear, value: progress) // << here !!
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
```

[Test code is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestPieProgress.swift)

#### Original

Here is possible approach (tested & works with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2):

1. You need to specify `animatableData` for your shape as below

   struct PieShape: Shape {
   var progress: Double = 0.0

   ```
    var animatableData: Double {
        get {
            self.progress
        }
        set {
            self.progress = newValue
        }
    }
    ...
   ```
2. then add animation to `Circle`

   Circle()
   .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1)
   .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.width, alignment: .center)
   .padding()
   .overlay(
   PieShape(progress: Double(self.progress))
   .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 10, height: geometry.size.width - 10 , alignment: .center)
   .foregroundColor(.blue)
   )
   .animation(Animation.linear) // << here !!

and that's it. For testing (only!) you can add the following in `PieProgress`

```
.onAppear {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10) {
        self.progress = 0.72
    }
}
```

Note: to use `PieProgress` as reused component it would be reasonable to make `progress` as `@Binding`, just in case.

Comment: I've changed it to @Binding. Thank you.

Comment: but where do you use this animatableData ?